# How to write a line to text file when particular condition is satisfied

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, save

I have a loop and checking one condition as follows

```
 while (t<len(var)):
        PR=y
        ...
        if z[t]<PR :
              pass_check=1
        else:
              pass_check=0 
      t=t+1
```

# check z for all samples and print the result

```
if pass_check==1:
print ('Test is  pass')
elif pass_check==0:
print ('Test is  fail')
else:
print ('Test is  fail')
```

## Goal

How to write Test is pass or fail in a text file depending upon the condition if all samples are 1 or 0 respectively

Comment: give your full code.

Comment: @ Vikas Damodar PR is columns  of data calculated from y and z is another array . Using t comparison is done.I am unable to attach all samples .

Comment: I don't understand; why don't just write it to a file? `open('your_file','w').write('Test is pass' if pass_check==1 else 'Test is fail')`

Comment: am wondering the same

Comment: @ mshsayem .It worked.! Was thinking in very tough way. :) . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it to a file like this:

```
with open('your_file', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write('Test is pass' if pass_check==1 else 'Test is fail')
```

Comment: @ mshsayem One question I have in this . Can I plot one constant line 1 to show it pass in the graph for all samples

Comment: I don't understand; can you explain more?

Comment: I am checking for all samples whether z[t]<PR. If it is  true then  pass_check=1 else 0. So in the matplotlib graph I want to show a constant line 1 if test is pass or 0 if test is fail. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I never used _matplotlib_; but it should be possible.

Comment: @ mshsayem . Now information is saved in file. Just wanted to pass the same information through plot.